# Exception mechanism issue in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception

I am calling a function and I am throwing an exception in that function. But I don't want to catch that in the same function but want to catch it where that function was called, like here is my example code.

```
void foo()throw(...){
  std::cout << "FOO" <<std::endl;
  throw "Found"; 
}
void main(){
  try{
      foo();
  }
  catch(...){
   std::cout << "exception catched" <<std::endl;
  }
}
```

But it is crashing at the point where I am throwing the exception in foo function, but I want to catch it in the main function.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
throw;
```

`throw` with no operand rethrows the exception that is currently being handled.  That means it can only be used in a `catch` block.  Since you aren't in a `catch` block when the `throw;` is executed, the program is terminated.

You need to throw *something*, like a runtime error: `throw std::runtime_error("oops");`.

---

Note also that exception specifications (e.g. the `throw(...)` in `void foo() throw(...)`) should not be used.  For an explanation as to why, see ["A Pragmatic Look at Exception Specifications."](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm)

Comment: Actually i was throwing exception like throw "Found....". i forgot to write found.

Comment: Well, we can't help you solve your problem if you don't tell us what your problem is.  If you add `#include <iostream>` to the top of the [new] code in your question and compile it with Visual C++ 2010 SP1, you will find that it compiles and runs without error.

Answer (score 0):

Got answer my own question at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wfa0edys%28v=VS.80%29.aspx